# Internet only works with tor enabled

Tags: firefox, network-configuration, dns

I installed tor, then wanted to configure my firefox browser to work with tor.  I had to do this as to use python/firefox anonymously to scrape data.  I was successfully able to use tor through firefox.  After wanting to go back to normal internet, I changed Configure Proxies to Access the Internet back to No Proxy, and now my internet wont work at all.  I cant connect to the internet through my terminal or firefox.  It will only work if I set SOCKS Host = 127.0.0.1 and Port back to 9150.  Any advice?  Chrome doesnt work at all either ..

im on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Note that running browsers - other than the Tor Browser - through Tor is officially recommended against due to the possibility that they could leak identifying information, regardless of whether you believe you've successfully proxied them: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by refreshing my dhcp through the terminal..

```
sudo dhclient -r  #refreshed ip
sudo dhclient  # restarted ip
```